# Find multiple files open write new line save

Tags: bash

In Linux I need to write a new line in the same file saved in multiple different directories.

They are saved for example in:

```
Home/user1/settings/settings.ini
Home/user2/settings/settings.ini    
...     
Home/user500/settings/settings.ini
```

How can I do it?

Comment: `for ((i = 1; i <= 500; i++)); do .... "/home/user$i/settings/settings.ini"...; done`??

Answer (score 0):

That will do:

```
for file in /home/*/settings/settings.ini; do
    echo >> "${file}"
done
```

Comment: `echo` already writes a newline after its (zero or more) arguments; `echo >> "$file"` suffices. (In fact, `echo -e "\n"` would write *two* newlines. `echo -ne "\n"` would be the long, non-standard way of writing a single newline.)

Answer (score 0):

With find:

```
find /home/*/settings -name 'settings.ini' -exec sh -c 'echo >> {}' \;
```